# Gradle - JARs copied into WEB-INF getting overwritten by GoogleAppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, web-inf

I'm currently using Gradle to compile and upload my Java code to GoogleAppEngine. It compiles fine locally, the problem is that the JAR libraries that the code is dependent upon are not within the "WEB-INF" folder on GAE.

I'm currently using War to copy the JAR files to WEB-INF using:

```
copy {
    from 'libs'
    into 'build/exploded-war/WEB-INF'
    include '**/*.jar'
}
```

The problem is that if it does this before the "gaeUpdate" command then the WEB-INF folder is overwritten and the JARs are deleted and thus not uploaded. If it does it after the gaeUpdate command then it's too late, the files have already been uploaded to the server and they are thus not uploaded.

It's important to note that if I enter "gradle" in the console without the "gaeUpdate" then the JARs don't get deleted, it's only when the "gaeUpdate" is added that they appear to get removed.

Is there way to upload the files after the "build" folder has been created but before the server upload?

Comment: The Jar files are put into `WEB-INF` automatically, so perhaps you haven't declared the dependencies correctly. Adding something to the exploded war doesn't add it to the war archive.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks for the reply, much appreciated!

In my dependencies section I have:
"compile files('./libs/mylibrary1.jar')
 compile files('./libs/mylibrary2.jar')"

It's the correct path because the console isn't throwing any "NoClassDefFound" errors which it obviously would if it couldn't find the library (The error is only thrown when I try to run it on GAE). I'm really stumped as to why my precompiled local jars are not being included or why (after I manually include them) they're only being removed when "gaeUpdate" is called.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hard to say. I never had this problem, even when including Jars from the file system. "or why (after I manually include them) they're only being removed when "gaeUpdate" is called." As I said, adding Jars to the exploded War won't add them to the War archive. Perhaps `gaeUpdate` uses the latter. Also, it isn't clear from your question where you put that `copy` block. Unless you wrap this block with a task action, it will get executed in the configuration phase, before any task has executed. Try to replace `copy` with `war`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks again! The "copy" block is inside of war in a task action which I execute in the command line (i.e. I call gradle AddJar gaeUpdate). With your first point, are you saying that if I called "compile files(...)" on a pre-existing Jar then it should have been automatically added to WEB-INF?

Comment: Move the `copy` block to the top level, replace `copy` with `war`, and call just `gradle gaeUpdate`. Yes, Jars should be added automatically. You might be misconfiguring something.

Comment: @Peter Ok great, thanks!

Could the lack of JARs being auto-included be because I call "Gradle gaeUpdate" on one project which in turn compiles several other projects and the JAR library is a dependency of one of those projects opposed to the root project?

Comment: As long as you define the correct project dependencies, it should just work.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser No luck with the war block unfortunately, I added "war {
        from 'libs'
        into 'build/exploded-war'
        include '**/*.jar'
    }" to my build.gradle and it doesn't copy it, not even if I don't do "gaeUpdate". Very strange!

Comment: It should be `into "WEB-INF/lib"`, not `into "build/exploded-war"` (that path will be created *inside* the War!).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Sorry - My mistake, that's what I tried initially.

I did notice something interesting however. I call "compile project(':mySubproject')" to compile each of my sub projects from my root project (and, as I say, it doesnt include the JAR in exploded war of either the subproject or the root project). If I compile the subproject directly however, I *do* get the library JAR within the subprojects exploded war folder!

Comment: For reference the "compile project(':mySubproject')" is inside of the dependencies of the root project and it's definitely being compiled because I don't get compilation errors until it tries to access the library when running on GAE.